# Is it possible to use regex for matching with a condition?

Tags: regex, vim

I posted this question on [super user](https://superuser.com/questions/686354/is-it-possible-use-regex-for-matching-with-a-condition) and I was suggested to post this question on stackoverflow.

I really like vim and today I faced with the intresting problem and I think it can be done via regexp but I can't form out proper one.

I've got a very big sql-file. It consolidates many different queries. File has content with something like this:

```
select * from hr.employees, oe.orders, oe.order_items
select * from hr.employess, oe.orders, hr.job_history
select * from oe.customers, oe.orders, hr.employees
select * from hr.employees, hr.departments, hr.locations
```

How can I select only that lines, which has only one match with `hr.` on the line?. For example above it will be first and third lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it is possible to match such lines. This pattern matches:

```
^\%(\%(hr\.\)\@!.\)*hr\.\%(\%(hr\.\)\@!.\)*$
```

Some people like to reduce the amount of backslash-escaping by using the very magic switch `\v`. Then the same pattern becomes

```
\v^%(%(hr\.)@!.)*hr\.%(%(hr\.)@!.)*$
```

(Here I used non-capturing parentheses `\%(...\)` but capturing parentheses `\(...\)` would work just as well.)

The question is: What do you want to do with these lines? Delete them?

In that case you could use the `:global` command:

```
:g/\v^%(%(hr\.)@!.)*hr\.%(%(hr\.)@!.)*$/d
```

More information at

- `:h :global`
- `:h /\v`
- `:h /\%(`
- `:h /\@!`

Answer (score 3):

To check if line contains only single occurrence of `hr.` use regex pattern

`^(?=.*\bhr\.)(?!.*\bhr\..*\bhr\.).*` with `m` modifier. I suggest to use `grep -P` utility.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: awesome graphics. looks almost like the EBNF latex package

Comment: You _need_ to use a PCRE-compatible regexp engine, indeed, because your regexp syntax won't work with Vim (but can be rewritten as such).

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ: I've read your answer in full, and also the question, which explicitly mentions Vim, so a note that this cannot be directly applied there might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

For that, you need to combine a *negative lookbehind* with a *negative lookahead* assertion; i.e. the currently matching pattern must not match before nor afterwards in the same line. In Vim, the atoms for those are `\@<!` and `\@!`, respectively.

The pattern to find a single occurrence of X is therefore this:

```
/\%(X.*\)\@<!X\%(.*X\)\@!/
```

Applied to your pattern `hr.`:

```
/\%(hr\..*\)\@<!hr\.\%(.*hr\.\)\@!/
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this I always find easier to split it into multiple uses of the regex.  If I were going to filter through this with grep, I'd do this:

```
grep "hr\." foo.sql
```

and that gives me all the lines with "hr.", even the ones with two.

Now I pipe that output through grep again and ask for it to ignore lines with `hr.` appearing twice:

```
grep "hr\." foo.sql | grep -v "hr\..*hr\."
```

I know you're talking about vim, but I'm showing alternatives that might be helpful and might be a good deal clearer.